# How to delete a tags in influxDB Cloud or influxDB explore?

Tags: influxdb

[How to delete a tags in influxDB Cloud or influxDB explore? Just like the tags: scripts, thx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFe0B.png)

Comment: In fact, 'scripts' is not a tag, but a value of tag 'source'.

Answer (score 0):

```
influx delete --bucket default \
--start '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' \
--stop $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") 
--predicate  "host=\"some-hostname\""
```

This will delete the data points for the host tag with the name "some-hostname".
I've not found a way to completely remove a tag